# Couldn't find 'cucumber' generator with Rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

When I try to run cucumber in my Rails project I'm getting this error.

I tried to run

```
ruby script/generate cucumber
```

and I'm getting the error

```
Couldn't find 'cucumber' generator
```

I have search a lot and didn't find any working solution. Following are my configs

```
rails version 2.3.8

Bundler version 1.0.15
```

GemFile

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem "bundler"
gem "rails", "= 2.3.8"
gem "i18n", "= 0.4.1"
gem "mysql"
gem 'delayed_job', '= 2.0.3'
gem 'daemons', '= 1.0.10'
gem "bundler"
gem "warden"
gem "warden_oauth"
gem "json"
gem 'haml'
gem "savon", "= 0.8.3"
gem "crack", "= 0.1.8"
gem "httpi", "= 0.7.8"
gem "gyoku", "= 0.2.0"

gem "soap4r"

gem "test-unit"
gem "cancan"
gem "color-logger", '>=0.0.3'
gem "searchlogic"

gem "formtastic", "= 1.1.0"
gem "faker", "= 0.3.1"
gem "populator"
gem "hoptoad_notifier"

gem 'builder', '~> 2.1.2'
gem 'rspec', '~> 1.3.0'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 1.3.2'
gem 'gherkin', '~> 2.1.4'
gem 'cucumber', '~> 0.8.5'
gem 'cucumber-rails', '~> 0.3.2'
gem 'capybara', '~> 0.4.0'
gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 0.6.0'



source "http://gems.github.com"
gem "mislav-will_paginate", "~> 2.3.11"

gem "fastercsv"
gem "spreadsheet" 
gem "logging"
```

The following is my entire gem list

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.9, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.3.8)
actionpack (3.0.9, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.3.8)
activemodel (3.0.9, 3.0.1, 3.0.0)
activerecord (3.0.9, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.3.8)
activeresource (3.0.9, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.3.8)
activesupport (3.0.9, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.3.8)
addressable (2.2.6)
annotate (2.4.0)
arel (2.0.10, 1.0.1)
authlogic (2.1.6)
autotest-growl (0.2.9, 0.2.6)
bcrypt-ruby (2.1.2)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.15)
cancan (1.6.5, 1.5.1, 1.4.1)
capistrano (2.5.19)
capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
capybara (1.0.0, 0.4.1.2, 0.4.0)
celerity (0.8.9, 0.8.8, 0.8.2)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
childprocess (0.2.0, 0.1.7, 0.1.3)
ci_reporter (1.6.4)
color-logger (0.0.3)
colored (1.2)
columnize (0.3.2)
configuration (1.2.0)
crack (0.1.8)
cucumber (1.0.2, 0.10.0, 0.9.3, 0.8.7)
cucumber-rails (1.0.2, 0.3.2)
culerity (0.2.15, 0.2.12)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
daemons (1.1.0, 1.0.10)
database_cleaner (0.6.7, 0.6.0)
delayed_job (2.0.3)
devise (1.1.7, 1.1.3)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
differ (0.1.2)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
factory_girl (1.3.3, 1.3.2)
factory_girl_rails (1.0.1)
faker (0.9.5, 0.3.1)
fakeweb (1.3.0)
fastercsv (1.5.4, 1.5.3)
fastthread (1.0.7)
ffi (1.0.9, 0.6.3)
formtastic (1.1.0)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
gherkin (2.4.6, 2.4.5, 2.3.3, 2.2.9, 2.1.5)
guid (0.1.1)
gyoku (0.2.0)
haml (3.1.2, 3.0.25, 3.0.23)
haml-rails (0.3.4)
has_scope (0.5.0)
highline (1.6.1)
hoe (2.8.0)
hoptoad_notifier (2.4.11, 2.4.9, 2.4.6, 2.3.12)
hpricot (0.8.3)
httpclient (2.2.1, 2.1.6.1)
httpi (0.7.8)
i18n (0.5.0, 0.4.2, 0.4.1)
inherited_resources (1.1.2)
jquery-rails (0.2.7, 0.2.5)
json (1.5.3, 1.5.2, 1.4.6)
json_pure (1.5.3, 1.5.1, 1.4.6)
launchy (2.0.5, 0.3.7)
lazy_high_charts (1.1.1)
linecache (0.43)
little-plugger (1.1.2)
logging (1.5.2)
machinist (2.0.0.beta2)
mail (2.2.19, 2.2.15, 2.2.9)
meta_search (0.9.8)
mime-types (1.16)
mislav-will_paginate (2.3.11)
mocha (0.9.12)
mongrel (1.1.5)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.2.11, 0.2.6)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.1.0, 2.0.23)
net-ssh-gateway (1.0.1)
nifty-generators (0.4.6)
nokogiri (1.5.0, 1.4.4, 1.4.3.1)
oauth (0.4.5, 0.4.4)
paper_trail (2.0.0)
paperclip (2.3.8, 2.3.5)
passenger (3.0.7)
polyglot (0.3.2, 0.3.1)
populator (1.0.0, 0.2.5)
rack (1.2.3, 1.2.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.0)
rack-mount (0.6.14, 0.6.13)
rack-test (0.6.1, 0.5.7, 0.5.6)
rails (3.0.9, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.3.8)
rails3-generators (0.17.4, 0.14.0)
rails3-jquery-autocomplete (0.6.6)
rails3_acts_as_paranoid (0.0.4)
rails_best_practices (0.9.0)
railties (3.0.9, 3.0.1, 3.0.0)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rcov (0.9.9)
rdoc (3.9.1)
responders (0.6.2)
rspec (2.6.0, 2.5.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.1, 1.3.2)
rspec-core (2.6.4, 2.5.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.1)
rspec-expectations (2.6.0, 2.5.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.1)
rspec-mocks (2.6.0, 2.5.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.1)
rspec-rails (2.6.1, 2.5.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.1, 1.3.4)
ruby-debug (0.10.4)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.4)
ruby-ole (1.2.11.1)
ruby-progressbar (0.0.10)
ruby_parser (2.0.6, 2.0.5)
rubyzip (0.9.4)
savon (0.8.3)
searchlogic (2.4.28, 2.4.27)
selenium-webdriver (2.3.2, 0.2.2, 0.1.3, 0.0.29)
sexp_processor (3.0.5)
shoulda (2.11.3)
show_for (0.2.4, 0.2.3)
simple_form (1.3.1, 1.2.2)
soap4r (1.5.8)
spork (0.8.5, 0.8.4)
spreadsheet (0.6.5.7, 0.6.5.5)
sqlite3 (1.3.4)
term-ansicolor (1.0.6, 1.0.5)
test-unit (2.3.1, 2.3.0, 1.2.3)
thor (0.14.6, 0.14.4)
treetop (1.4.10, 1.4.9, 1.4.8)
trollop (1.16.2)
tzinfo (0.3.29, 0.3.24, 0.3.23)
warden (1.0.5, 1.0.4, 1.0.3, 0.10.7)
warden_oauth (0.1.1)
web-app-theme (0.6.3, 0.6.2)
will_paginate (3.0.pre2, 2.3.15)
xpath (0.1.4, 0.1.3, 0.1.2)
yajl-ruby (0.8.2)
ZenTest (4.5.0, 4.4.0)
```

Comment: what does your gem list say about these gems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your gem list, you have a lot of cucumber versions. You might want first to ensure you are running the correct cucumber.

Here are some suggestions:
 - if you arent using rvm, i suggest you do since you can isolate a certain cucumber version for your project there(assuming you are working on other projects that require cucumber)
 - if you already are, i suggest you uninstall all your cucumber versions and do another bundle install, it should give you the correct version now

Comment: hi @corroded, you are right... I removed all the cucumber versions and cucumber-rails versions and re-install then through bundle install, now its working fine, thanks a lot

Comment: that is what you called experience :D